# Conditional splitting

Tags: c#, c++, regex, parsing

I am writing a .cpp parser in C#. I need to split the file by some operators. However, I have two delimiters, `-` and `->`.

I want to split the file by `>` when it doesn't have a `-` preceding, otherwise `>` delimiter would also split the `->`.

Should I use regex, or any different solutions?

Comment: Your question is very broad. What have you tried so far? Maybe we can help with the errors/exceptions you are getting?

Comment: yes, regex would be the simplest IMO

Comment: [Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: C++ is notoriously difficult to parse. You're probably better off using a parser generator (or even better, an existing library like clang) rather than hand-writing your own from scratch.

Comment: No, you do not want to write .cpp parser in C#. You want to use [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# `String.Split` is enough:

```
  String source = "1->2>3->4->5>6"; 

  // "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"
  var items = source.Split(new String[] { "->", ">" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: But a parser/scanner should also tell you the operator.

Answer (score 0):

Just show how to do this use Regex:

```
String source = "1->2>3->4->5>6";
//replace all > to ->
source=Regex.Replace(source,"(?<!-)>","-$0");
```